# GP web services or econnect to process payment against newly created sales invoice after payment gateway returns success

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect, dynamics-gp-api

I have been working on a light weight shopping cart type system for one of our applications.  I have the cart creating a sales invoice in GP through web service CreateSalesInvoice.  Then I have code to interface with our payment gateway sandbox and can process payment and get approval.  The last piece of my prototype is to show the payment has taken place in GP.  There are no web service offerings for processing a payment.  I have searched for documentation on how to do this but found very little.  If you have knowledge or references on how to accomplish this, your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're back for more GP fun? It's always an adventure with this software. Just so I am understanding your environment, are you attempting to pass payment information *to* GP and then you need to query for when the payment processing has taken place? Are you familiar with the posting process in GP? That is relevant to your approach.

Comment: Yes, I'm back....Nothing is very straightforward and the documentation, at times, seems lacking.  As far as setup goes...I have created the sales invoice and passed into it the next SOPnumber, once successful, I send credit card info to payment gateway.  Upon approval code returned from gateway, I want to update GP with the payment.  I am not that familiar with the posting process.  I just want to pass the payment data to GP so when things are posted the invoice shows as paid.

Comment: Ok so a payment is called a Cash Receipt https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623675.aspx Remember how I recommended you store your SOPNUMBER ? You will need provide the SOPNUMBE to choose which document to create a receipt for. Otherwise, you will need to create an unposted batch of unapplied cash receipts, to which a user in GP will need to apply manually then post. Do you also need a process to update your application with data from GP when the payment is posted?

Comment: If you do, then I would recommend Victoria Yudin's query to get the apply detail: https://victoriayudin.com/2010/02/15/sql-view-with-ar-apply-detail/

Comment: And yes, just to confuse you, even though it's called a Cash Receipt, it can be Cash, Check or Credit Card type, each with different field requirements and default values...

Comment: I pass the SOPNumber to the payment gateway so the customer has it for their records.  As a result I know what SOPnumber to use for the Cash receipt.  The customer loads their cart with items, then enters payment details and clicks Buy.  My code will create the sales invoice, process their payment and then update the newly created sales invoice with the payment.  I see by your msdn link that we are back to using eConnect.  uggggg!

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm used to doing everything in SQL and eConnect. The Web Services are missing so many features that I try to avoid them at all costs. Try here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508543.aspx

Comment: This looks promising...you're awesome.  I will give this a try.  Thank you for the feedback.  Hopefully my prototype will work as I have envisioned.  I don't work with GP that much, so I'm sure I'm not thinking of something but at least I can demonstrate a proof of concept with my team.

Comment: The part that will trip you up is the posting process and keeping everything in sync. What happens if you create a sales order in GP and then a payment doc and the user deletes it? What happens if the user posts the sales document and deletes only the payment? In theory, your users wont do this, but in practice it will happen. Since posting is a user process that cannot be automated, issues almost always arise with keeping the data in sync between GP and other applications. So far you haven't done anything that you could avoid though so don't worry too much.